# Building an 18' x 8 foot free standing deck with pergola

Tags: deck

My plan is to build an 18 x 8 foot free standing deck at the front entrance to my home. Then add a pergola over the entire deck.
My area is sandy soil. No underground utilities in the area I want to place the deck. 
The plan was to extend my 8- 4 x 4 posts 8 feet over the deck. I'll only be able to extend 3 of the 4 posts, closest to the house, up the 8 feet. Too many windows and door close together. (see photo). Deck would be between door and right window moving left between the double windows, near satellite dish.
This house was built 19 years ago. There seems to be a concern among the forums that we should not place posts closer to the house, than 3 feet. There has not been any soil disturbed since the house was placed on it's foundation, 19 years ago.(per neighbors). [image: house front]This is a modular home (stick built in a factory, no steel framing). 
The local code inspector was not concerned about the free standing deck, when I talked to him. He was more concerned about the potential lateral forces on the Pergola. I plan on bracing the pergola at the corners and notching the overhead 2x6's and 2x4's.
My question: would you think it safe to place my posts closer than 3 feet to the house?